# Adding an ID to Google Map Marker then targeting it

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've created a google map using the Google Maps API v3 and have added a custom marker, I have added an ID to the Marker constructor which I am hoping to target with additional JS using jQuery, at the moment however when I simply try something like $( '#'+marker.id ).hide(); nothing happens?

Could anyone advise me on how to properly access this marker id?

My maker code is as follows:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            externalURL: 'http://www.google.com',
            position: defaults.center,
            map: map,
            icon: markerImg,
            id: 'marker'
        });
```

and then I use the following code to create a jQuery object to target:

```
var mapMarker = $( '#'+marker.id );
    mapMarker.hide();
```

Comment: Is there any error? Check your console.

Comment: No theres no errors, it just doesn't seem to register the id

Comment: @Jorge i'm still unable to target the id using your answer?

Comment: You won't be able to access it using the jQuery "$" selector.  You need to iterate through an array of all the markers (which are google.maps.Marker objects) looking for the one with that id.

Comment: hey could you give me an example? i will only ever have one marker on the map, i basically want to be able to add a class of is-active to the #marker when the map comes into view?

Answer (score 5):

After creating a marker with

```
var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                   externalURL: 'http://www.google.com',
                   position: defaults.center,
                   map: map,
                   icon: markerImg,
                   id: 'marker'
               });
```

To remove it from the map, use:

```
myMarker.setMap(null);
```

To hide the marker marker from view, use:

```
myMarker.setVisible(false);
```

If you need to have a lot of markers to access later, consider:

```
var allMyMarkers = [];
allMyMarkers.push( myMarker );
```

To access a specific id, consider:

```
for(var i=0;i<allMyMarkers.length;i++){
    if(allMyMarkers[i].id === "marker"){
        allMyMarker[i].setMap(null);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ideally I would like to add a class to #marker when the map comes into view as to animate it from 0 to 100% width, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just hide the marker use this:

```
marker.setMap(null);
```

Is that solution for your problem ?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but it's a good suggestion when somebody only wants to hide it.