# How to drag and drop a google maps marker?

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-maps, webdriver, laravel-dusk

I'm trying to write end-to-end browser tests using webdriver (Laravel Dusk) for a case using drag and drop of a google maps marker.

[The documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/dusk#using-the-mouse) is straight forward about doing this given a CSS selector to the marker icon, but I can't figure out how to add a selector to a marker. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18129052/4233593) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2564320/4233593) provided great answers for manipulating the marker inside the canvas, but nothing for external references.

Comment: You can manage the google marker's only  with google maps api ..  these include also feature for drag an drop ..

Comment: @scaisEdge thank you, yes I know how to make a marker `draggable` and listen for the events - this is how my app works. However, I need a way to be able to automate unit tests so that I don't have to manually test this each cycle.

Comment: Were you able to attach ids to your markers as per the 2  links you mentioned?